# PHP get secundary thing in a link

Tags: php, url

i want to check if there is anything behind /index.php/'
parameters must be ignored and the baseurl without /index.php/ also must be ignored.
i know about

```
if (strpos($url, 'contact') !== false){ }
```

but i dont know how to use it to check the second part of the url for anything but parameters.
how am i supposed to do this?

example:

```
localhost:8080/ - returns false.
localhost:8080/index.php - returns false.
localhost:8080/index.php/ - returns false.
localhost:8080/index.php?id=0 - returns false.
localhost:8080/index.php/contact - returns true.
```

Comment: You can use basename + parse_url or explose example:echo basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));

Comment: You added the Joomla tag here. What are you trying to do? If you add some context you might get a better answer.

Comment: the joomla tag is here because the website is build on joomla.
this result in only having one page to work with instead of for every link a seperate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the string.

```
$url = "localhost:8080/index.php/contact?id=0";

// Split the string using delimiter "/index.php/"
$url = explode("/index.php/", $url);

// We have parts
if (isset($url[1])) {

    // We want the first part after "/index.php/"
    // And we don't want anything after ?
    $url = explode("?", $url[1])[0];

// We have no parts, change the array to an empty string
} else {

   $url = "";
}
```

Comment: that gets all the parts of the url,
how do i get any value behind index.php

Comment: i tried what was in your edit but,
i got this error: Undefined offset: 1 when i try to load localhost:8080/index.php
localhost:8080/index.php/ is fine.
localhost:8080/ and localhost:8080 also give errors

Comment: Yes you need to check if the string is empty.

Comment: with this code:

    $part = explode("index.php/", $url);
    if (isset($part[1])) {
    $part = explode("?", $part)[0];
    }

only the localhost:8080/index.php works everything else gives:
explode) expects parameter 2 to be string, array given. on the rule of

    $part = explode("?", $part)[0];

i thought the explode creates a array?

Comment: Basename(parse_url())  is the better way

Comment: how do i check if the $part equals "" or "/".
it tried things like if($part == '/') but that doesn't help.
no matter what i do the /index.php/ is the only url that does work and all the others like localhost:8080, localhost:8080/ and localhost:8080/index.php don't work correctly
the localhost:8080/index.php/contact works correctly

Comment: i have figured it out. 
i check if $part is set and if explode("?", $part[1])[0] !== "/index.php/") and put the code i wanted in the else for the index page with all possible urls to get to the index page,

anyways thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, no worries, I edited my answer with a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can regexp what comes after index.php

```
preg_match("/index\.php\/(.*?)^/ims","localhost:8080/index.php/contact",$matches );
print_r($matches);
```